# How to get client weather from IP Address with Yahoo Weather API

Tags: javascript, yahoo-weather-api

I'm aware that Yahoo Weather uses it's own codes to determine which area to get the weather for. I want to show the weather for each user visiting my site when the page loads, but I'm having some trouble here.

My key issues here are:

- How to get the user's geographical location (preferably city name) from the IP Address.
- How to get the area code in Yahoo Weather for the user's city.
- How to post the weather back to my page.

I don't really have a clue where to start here so any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this use [IPInfo](http://ipinfo.io/) to get user's actual address and city.

The Yahoo Weather documentation asks you to use **woeid** of the city, but you can use the YQL and the Yahoo Geolocation API to get this.